# Azure Logout Redirect (post_logout_redirect_uri) is not working

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-active-directory

The Azure logout page is not redirecting the user after complete the logout. It is returning just this message:

> You signed out of your account. It's a good idea to close all browser
>   windows.

I tried different logout URLs that I've found around:

- https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmicway.com.au%2F
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https//micway.com.au/
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https://micway.com.au

But they didn't work at all.

The only that is weird is that, if I check the Network tab on DevTools, it seems that the page is loading the redirected website content, but it's not showing it on the browser.

Comment: Have you added that URL as a reply URL for the app in Azure AD? Could you post a screenshot of the Network tab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As **juunas** said in the comment, I just added the Logout URL to the Reply URLs list and worked.

Comment: What was the reply URL you ended up using? i.e. which format? Can't be any of the above because it won't allow query string parameters, etc.

Comment: I did test, just need to add the URL domain is OK, don't need to add full URL.

Comment: I added the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/logout` to my redirect URI list and still it doesnt redirect

Comment: And is there a way you can test this locally? The logout URL must be https, so as of right now I cannot verify that it works on my local setup

Answer (score 1):

Check also what type of account you're testing with. I found this strange post logout redirection behavior:

- It doens't work for root accounts of the tenant, that is my personal account, which created Azure subscription.
- But it works for new accounts I created inside of my subscription.