# Frustration using Blazor self-hosted, AzureAD MIP configuration and 'authentication/logout' not redirecting back to application

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, single-sign-on

I have a self-hosted Blazor application and I have it configured to use Azure AD single tenant sign-on to secure partial areas of the app. This is working exactly as planned at the moment in so far as when a user clicks on a restricted area they are presented with the Microsoft SSO popup and can login and be authenticated and access the restricted area. My frustration comes when a user clicks on 'Logout'. The Microsoft SSO popup is shown and the user can select the account to sign out of and then get shown the generic 'You have signed out' page BUT it does not redirect back to my application. I am pretty sure I have missed something in config but I have tried so many variations and I still cannot get it to work.

Here is what I have setup
I have this configured for my client
[image: Client App Config]

And this is what I have configured for the server
[image: Server Config]

This is the appsettings.json for my client
[image: Client JSON]

And this is appsettings.json for my server
[image: Server Config]

And in my client 'LoginDisplay.razor' I have tried using using the default setting for logging out and even tried the following but to no avail

[image: Logout]

Whenever I log out I see the logout page OK
[image: Logout]

But the URL is confusing

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{GUID-HERE}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fauthentication%2Flogout-callback&client-request-id=9a86a0bf-4e49-442a-9188-41585ce0ec93
```

And once logged only ever see this page

[image: Logged Out]

And I get no redirect. Is there something that I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

If you use .NET 7, instead of using Navigation.NavigateTo, use Navigation.NavigateToLogout, first parameter is authentication/logout, and second parameter is returnUrl

Answer (score 0):

Please check below points :

Try add **logout url i**n the manisfest of the application in azure portal .

[image]

for example : `https://localhost:7166/logout`

Also ***add the Logout URL even to the Reply URLs*** list as one of the url .  Also see [SO ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836956/azure-logout-redirect-post-logout-redirect-uri-is-not-working?rq=1)

> Please note that  logout redirect fails without the session .

If we request to uri something like "`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2Flogout%2F%3F&client_id=xx`;" without a session, it may take you to the page showing, "Successfully logged out", but it may not redirect back to app, as AzureAD, won't just redirect without a proper session since as it is  not a safe practice.

**References:**

1. [Send a sign-out request](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc?view=azureelasticdbjobsps-0.8.33#send-a-sign-out-request)
2. [how to implement a post-logout| SO ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71915956/how-to-implement-a-post-logout-with-azure-ad-in-c-sharp-mvc/71938184#71938184)